# How do I bind a bunch of /24 subnets (secondary) in one shot?

Tags: 14.04, networking

I need to bind a bunch of /24 IPv4 subnets as secondary. The primary /29 is already set during the installation of Ubuntu 14x. How do I bind the remainder /24 subnets in one shot instead of individual single IPs one at a time?

I tried this method by adding the below line in /etc/network/interfaces but it didn't work?

```
up route add [-net|-host] <host/net>/<mask> gw <host/IP> dev <Interface>

root@server:~# /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

I also tried this method too (below example, but did actual IPs and em1)

```
for i in {1..128}; do echo iface eth1:$i inet static >> /etc/network/interfaces; echo address 192.168.0.$i >> /etc/network/interfaces; echo netmask 255.255.255.0 >> /etc/network/interfaces; echo auto eth1:$i >> /etc/network/interfaces; done


root@server:~# service networking restart
stop: Job failed while stopping
start: Job is already running: networking
root@server:~# ifdown em1 && sudo ifup em1
```

Comment: Afaik you can not assign a whole subnet to an Ethernet device.

Comment: Why not? It just would not make sense that Ubuntu would not let you do that. Completely irrational, if true.

Comment: Perhaps I did not understand what you are trying to achieve. Why do you want to have several hundreds of IP addresses on one server?

Answer (score 0):

I run a couple of scripts with every new install. One is more for configurations and other other to add software.

Part of my script. Over time changed from 192. to 10. (and back), so I comment out one not currently used.

```
#NFS setup
fname_exp=/etc/exports
#nfs1="/mnt/data   192.168.1.0/24(rw,no_root_squash,async)"
#nfs2="/mnt/shared 192.168.1.0/24(rw,no_root_squash,async)"
nfs1="/mnt/data   10.0.0.0/24(rw,no_root_squash,async)"
nfs2="/mnt/shared 10.0.0.0/24(rw,no_root_squash,async)"

echo $nfs1 >> $fname_exp
echo $nfs2 >> $fname_exp
```

Comment: what does this have to do with my question? It's irrelevant.